# D3 pie chart updating issue, increasing size of focused slice

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm building a pie chart with D3 that can be updated with new information, and that also has a couple cool features.

Currently the pie chart functions just fine, but I'm having trouble with increasing the size of whichever slice has the mouse on top of it. I have done this:

```
cv_path.enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return cv_color(i); } )
  .attr("d", cv_arc)
  .each(function(d) { this._current = d; })
  .attr("stroke","white")
  .attr("stroke-width",1)
  .on("mouseenter", function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(350)
      .attr("d", arcOver)
      .attr("stroke","white")
      .attr("stroke-width",1);
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function(d) {
    d3.select(this).transition()
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("stroke","none")
      .attr("stroke","white")
      .attr("stroke-width",1);
```

Please forgive the duplication, I'm just trying to get things functioning. So, this actually works like I intended, but I ran into a problem. When the pie chart updates/transitions to represent the updated data it no longer keeps the chunk enlarged. It updates and acts as if my mouse is no longer there until I move it again. Is there a way where, when the graph updates, I can keep the chunk enlarged?

Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/22o1epyp/

If you hover your mouse over a slice it will enlarge, and once the graph updates you will notice that no slice is enlarged. This is the issue.

Comment: You could store whether a slice is larger with the data and, in the update selection, check that to decide which function to use to set `d`.

Comment: Hey Lars, any chance you could show me in the jsfiddle? I've given it a shot, but I'm having difficulty even enlarging a slice outside of the .on events I created. I'm not great with d3 yet so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/22o1epyp/2/) -- storing the state with the data doesn't actually work because the data is being updated, so I've stored it with the DOM node.